# How do I get ffmpeg to work on my website?

Tags: ffmpeg, command, system

ffmpeg works on my local computer when I provide the absolute path for it or make it work globally by editing the environment variables.

But on my website it doesn't work at all. I uploaded ffmpeg.exe, ffplay.exe, and ffprobe.exe to public_html/

Here is my code:

```php
<?php
  ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set ('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting (E_ALL);
  $image1 = "/home/mywebsitename/public_html/uploads2/1.png";
  $image2 = "/home/mywebsitename/public_html/uploads2/2.png";
  $ffmpeg = "/home/mywebsitename/public_html/ffmpeg";
  $command = $ffmpeg." -i ".$image1." -vf scale=100:-2 ".$image2;
  system($command);
?>
```

It's supposed to make one image file mimic another, while having some differences in size and quality.

I enabled the system function in my php.ini file which allowed it to work, and it doesn't give me an error on that anymore.

I also changed the permissions of all the files and folders involved(uploads2 folder, 1.png, 2.png, the ffmpeg programs) to 777 which allows everything from read, write and execute.

However, nothing outputted, and the files stayed the same. How do I get ffmpeg to work on my website?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: This is my code <?php
ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
ini_set ('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting (E_ALL);

$image1 = "/home/mywebsitename/public_html/uploads2/1.png";
$image2 = "/home/mywebsitename/public_html/uploads2/2.png";
$ffmpeg = "/home/mywebsitename/public_html/ffmpeg";
$command = $ffmpeg." -i ".$image1." -vf scale=100:-2 ".$image2;
system($command);
?>

Comment: @SamCordin Please edit your question and include the code as part of the question, not in the comments.

Comment: How do I add code? I'm new here. I did the backticks like they told me but my code is not appearing.

Comment: Technically it could be possible to install ffmpeg on a Unix OS, but it depends if the hosting supports it. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529796/how-to-use-ffmpeg-with-laravel-5-7-on-a-shared-hosting-with-limited-resources-ac

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg needs to be installed on the server that hosts your website and your user account must have permission to access FFmpeg on that server.

You cannot just upload a `.exe` file on a system and expect it to work as it is a Windows executable file and has other dependencies that are needed to run it on a **Windows** machine. Your website is *probably* running on a Linux-based machine.

If you are using a shared web hosting plan, you can ask your web hosting provider to see if they can provide you access to an FFmpeg instance installed on the server (which is very unlikely), or you can rent a VPS and have full access to the system to install and manage all the software you need including FFmpeg.

For image processing in PHP, there are other alternatives you can use such as the `GD` and `Imagick` extensions that are widely used and most likely are already installed in the environment that your website is running on. [**More information**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php)

Comment: Do I install the exe files to the server? To my knowledge, those 3 exe files are all I need. I could be wrong.

Comment: @SamCordin The exe files can only run on a Windows machine. If your server is using Linux, those files won't work and you have to install FFmpeg based on the installation steps for the Linux distribution that you are using.